# how to bind click event in angular js using requirejs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to bind click event using require js + angularjs

I try to bind the click event but it is bind the click event 
[Here is my code](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/mq2vdmxmx5qbfdd/testapp.zip?dl=0)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
<script data-main="main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ionic:'lib/ionic.bundle'
    },
    shim: {
        ionic : {exports : 'ionic'}
    }, priority: [
        'ionic'
    ],

    deps: [
        'bootstrap'
    ]
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
/*global define, require, console, cordova, navigator */

define(['ionic',  'app', 'routes'], function (ionic, angular, app) {
    'use strict';

    var $html,
        onDeviceReady = function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
        };

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    if (typeof cordova === 'undefined') {
        $html = angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
        angular.element().ready(function () {
            try {
                angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.stack || e.message || e);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

**app.js**

```
/*global define, require */

define(['ionic'],

    function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('app', [
            'ionic']);

        return app;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few bugs in your code... too many too list them all. See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n57L5sMIDuRcP3NMnnnP?p=preview) for the corrections.

1. The module `ionic` should be exported as `angular`.

   ```
   requirejs.config({
       paths: {
           ionic:'lib/ionic.bundle'
       },
       shim: {
           ionic : {exports : 'angular'}
       }, priority: [
           'ionic'
       ],

       deps: [
           'bootstrap'
       ]
   });
   ```
2. Ionic/Angular must be loaded first - or angular can't initialize itself.
3. In the routes you have to reference the controller by name - not by location

   ```
   /*global define, require */

   define(['app'], function (app) {
   'use strict';


   app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
       function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

           $stateProvider
               .state('login', {
                   url: "/login",
                   templateUrl: "login.html",
                   controller: 'controllers/LoginCtrl' // <-- should be 'LoginCtrl'
               })

           $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

       }]);       
   });
   ```

Comment: could you please example some bugs ?

Comment: Thanks for answer ..!! great anser .but could you please explain some bugs